# Avoid NA in column after pivot_wider()

Tags: r, tidyr

Is there a possibility to 'shift up' observations after `pivot_wider()` and remove `NA's` above an observation in a column ? I tried to `lag()` the columns, but this seems cumbersome. Obviously, I am not bound to this method but would prefer to stay in the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1111)

df <- data.frame(
  item = as.numeric(sample(1:20)),
  clust = as.numeric(sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE))
)

df %>%
  arrange(clust, item) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = clust, values_from = item, names_prefix = "Cluster_") %>%
  select(-rowid)
```

The current output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   Cluster_1 Cluster_2 Cluster_3
       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1         3        NA        NA
 2        13        NA        NA
 3        14        NA        NA
 4        15        NA        NA
 5        16        NA        NA
 6        17        NA        NA
 7        19        NA        NA
 8        20        NA        NA
 9        NA         1        NA
10        NA         4        NA
11        NA         6        NA
12        NA         7        NA
13        NA         8        NA
14        NA         9        NA
15        NA        12        NA
16        NA        18        NA
17        NA        NA         2
18        NA        NA         5
19        NA        NA        10
20        NA        NA        11
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
   Cluster_1 Cluster_2 Cluster_3
       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1         3         1         2
 2        13         4         5
 3        14         6        10
 4        15         7        11
 5        16         8        NA
 6        17         9        NA
 7        19        12        NA
 8        20        18        NA
```

I am aware, that this approach jeopardises the data set but it is solely for aesthetic reasons, as the tibble is subsequently exported to a LATEX document and aids only the visualisation of cluster grouping.

Comment: How many clusters do you have in your real data? Is it only 3 or is it a larger number you wouldn't be able to deal with manually?

Comment: The number of clusters depends on the underlying dataset. It is derived from the `Ckmeans.1d.dp()` and thus not controllable. I would like a universal solution where it transposed the item column in groups by the cluster number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1111)

df <- data.frame(
  item = as.numeric(sample(1:20)),
  clust = as.numeric(sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE))
)

df %>%
  arrange(clust, item) %>%
  group_by(clust) %>% 
  mutate(id =row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = clust, values_from = item, names_prefix = "Cluster_") %>%
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   Cluster_1 Cluster_2 Cluster_3
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1         3         1         2
#> 2        13         4         5
#> 3        14         6        10
#> 4        15         7        11
#> 5        16         8        NA
#> 6        17         9        NA
#> 7        19        12        NA
#> 8        20        18        NA
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. I tried the `group_by()` before the pivoting as well, but it seems that the usage of `rowid_to_column()` was a mistake. The function adds the rowIDs sequentially to a new column irrespective of the previous `group_by()`. The `row_number()` does respect the prior grouping.

Comment: (: Yep. I tried with rowid_to_column() as well. But rowid_... simply adds the rownames of the df, while row_number makes row_numbers per group. Best S.

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach using `split` and adapting the lengths.

```
s <- split(df$item, df$clust)
as.data.frame(lapply(s, function(x) `length<-`(sort(x), max(lengths(s)))))
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  3  1  2
# 2 13  4  5
# 3 14  6 10
# 4 15  7 11
# 5 16  8 NA
# 6 17  9 NA
# 7 19 12 NA
# 8 20 18 NA
```